# How to change routing as component: lazy() to simple routes

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, router, react-functional-component

I have a template, they are using this method of routing the components ,

```
import { lazy } from 'react'

// ** Document title
const TemplateTitle = '%s - Title'

// ** Default Route
const DefaultRoute = '/dashboard'

// ** Merge Routes
const Routes = [
  {
    path: '/dashboard',
    component: lazy(() => import('../../views/dashboard'))
  },
  {
    path: '/home',
    component: lazy(() => import('../../views/Home'))
  }
]

export { DefaultRoute, TemplateTitle, Routes }
```

But I like to to use function components ;

like this one

```
import React from 'react'

function Profile() {
    return <div>Profile</div>
}

export default Profile
```

So when I added a route as they template was created

```
 {
    path: '/profile',
    component: lazy(() => import('../../views/Profile'))
  },
```

I'm unable to access to it, So how could that be achieved and If switch to simple routing using hash router then is that possible to change that with few lines of code as all of template is made with lazy() routing method

Comment: Have you wrap your Switch with a React.Suspense?

Comment: No I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const Component = lazy(() => import('../../views/Profile'));

{
  path: '/profile',
  component: <Component />
},
```